# Next.js keep the state or send props when router.push

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and I am redirecting the user to next page using `router.push`

```js
router.push("/terminal_summary");
```

My Redux state is empty on the next page, but I need the data I have in the state. How do I keep it or at least how can I send some props with `router.state`?

I tried `router.push("/terminal_summary", undefined, { shallow: true });` but it doesn't work.

I have also tried:

```js
router.push({
  pathname: '/terminal_summary',
  query: props.terminalPayload
})
```

But it sends data in query parameter.

The best thing would be to keep all the data in state or at least I want to be able to redirect with props.

EDIT:

On the next page I'm trying to access the Redux state using `mapStateToProps`

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    terminalPayload: state.terminalPayload,
  };
}
```

But this state after redirecting is showing `initialState` instead of the changes I have done on the previous page.

So the value is `{}` but it is supposed to be an object like below.

```
{
   merchant: [{ /*multiple objects*/ }],
   products: [{ /* multiple products*/}],
   // other data
}
```

Please note, this is currently not saved in the db and supposed to be saved on the next page where I want to show the summary then ask user to save.

Another note, I can see the data from Redux DevTools in Chrome but when I access on the page it is `{}`.

EDIT 2:

here is the complete redux code:

configureStore.js

```
export default (initialState) => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxImmutableStateInvariant()))
  );
};
```

reducers/index.js

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  terminals,
  merchants,
  distributors,
  terminalPayload,
  roles,
  /* other reducers */
});

export default rootReducer;
```

initialState.js

```
export default {
  terminals: {
    imported: [],
  },
  merchants: [],
  distributors: [],
  terminalPayload: {},
  roles: [],
};
```

I'm using next.js so i have _app.js file where i have this code:

```
import configureStore from "../redux/configureStore";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  let state = {};
  const store = configureStore();

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...state} />
      </Layout>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

then i have some actions and where is how i subscribe to it

terminal.js

```
const terminal = (props) => {
     const router = useRouter();
     /* functions */
     /* i have a function here that use router.push('terminal_summary') to redirect user to next page */
     return /* jsx */
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    terminals: state.terminals,
    terminalPayload: state.terminalPayload,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    terminalActions: bindActionCreators(terminalActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(terminal);
```

terminal_summary.js

```
const terminalSummary = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();


  return (
    /* jsx */
  );
};

terminalSummary.propTypes = {
  terminalPayload: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    terminalPayload: state.terminalPayload, // this object is empty here {} which is supposed to be same as i had on terminal.js page
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(terminalSummary);
```

i have been looking into this and im not sure if it is something related to this:

`https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps`
`https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper`

Answer (score 9):

Nextjs doesn't really allow for route state like many other common client-side routing/navigation libraries, but you can send data via the query parameter and then "hide" them from the address bar using the `as` parameter of [router.push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush).

## Next.js 14

### Page Router

[useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router) - This appears to function the same as v13 and below.

Use the `as` option, same as older versions, e.g. `router.push(url, as, options)`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

...

router.push(
  {
    pathname: '/terminal_summary',
    query: props.terminalPayload
  },
  '/terminal_summary',
);
```

Reciever

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

...

const router = useRouter();
const terminalPayload = router.query; // <-- terminalPayload sent in query parameter
```

### App Router

The app router and `useRouter` hook ***do not*** have this functionality. Any data passed will be included with the URL path in the queryString.

[useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router): `router.push(href: string, { scroll: boolean })`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

...

router.push(`/terminal_summary?param=${terminalPayload}`);
```

## Next.js older

> `as` - Optional decorator for the URL that will be shown in the
> browser. Before Next.js 9.5.3 this was used for dynamic routes, check
> our previous docs to see how it worked

```js
router.push(
  {
    pathname: '/terminal_summary',
    query: props.terminalPayload
  },
  '/terminal_summary',
);
```

On the receiving route access the `query` object.

```js
const router = useRouter();
const terminalPayload = router.query; // <-- terminalPayload sent in query parameter
```

Comment: i really cant use router.query because i have a complexed object in the state i want to access on the next page, isn't there a better solution, i can see data in redux devtools in chrome

Comment: @WasifKhalil How complex could it be? Maybe you just send a guid in the query and the next page uses that to access redux state. An alternative could be to use dynamic routes and pass a "slug" as part of the URL, i.e. something like `/terminal_summary/${slugID}` and then fetch data from your redux state, or use a special state slice specifically for route transitions where you shove whatever data to state and push the route and check on receiving routes' components for any data that may be there.

Comment: i have edited my question for you to explain in details, the data is not saved yet and I'm not able to read state on the next page

Comment: sorry by mistake i edited ur answer, i edited the question now

Comment: @WasifKhalil No worries. IMHO unless that is a huge object (i.e. megabytes of data) I think sending with the route transition should be no problem. Are you saying when you save the `terminalPayload` object somewhere in your redux state before a `router.push(...)` that it isn't available yet to pull out of state on the next page?

Comment: yes drew this is exactly what i mean, i can see it from redux devtools but on page it is an empty object {}

Comment: @WasifKhalil Ok, do you mind updating your question to also include your redux code, i.e. the action creators used, the reducer(s), and the next page and how it subscribes to your redux store? If written correctly, even if the state hadn't updated by the time the UI reaches the next page, the next page should still at least rerender when state updates. Just speculating at this point, but maybe that page isn't checking for updated props after it's mounted.

Comment: i have edited the question to explain more

Comment: it worked  
this.props.router to retreive data did not work.
thanks @drew

Comment: I experimented with using the `as` param, but state was still resetting. I'm not confident this is a correct answer anymore after the server components overhaul.

Comment: @JohnMiller Thanks for the feedback. It would seem the masking functionality *does* still exist but it depends on whether or not you are using the App routing or the Page routing. I've updated my answer to have more current information.