# How to pass custom props to a dynamic page in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a component named `Card.js` that links to dynamic pages whenever a card is clicked. What I need is to pass a value like 'category' to the dynamic page `[id].js` so I can do some more logic over there.

Card.js

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import React from "react";

function Card({ id, post, category }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const Redirect = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push(`/${id}`);
  };
  return (
    <div
      onClick={Redirect}
    >
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

[id].js

```
  function PostPage() {

  
    return (
      <>
        
      </>
    );
  }
  
  export default PostPage;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js keep the state or send props when router.push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758812/next-js-keep-the-state-or-send-props-when-router-push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a value using `router.push()` by adding it to the url query of the next page

```js
const Redirect = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push({pathname: `/${id}`, query: { category: category }});
};
```

and you can use it on your `[id].js` by `useRouter`

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function PostPage() {
    const category = router.query.category // <--- category here
  
    return (
      <>
        
      </>
    );
}
  
export default PostPage;
```

Comment: I did the following `router.push(`/${id}`, { query: { category: category } }); but now it doesn't redirect to the page anymore. the category gets displayed in the url but the ID which is used for the redirect doesn't appear anymore

Comment: @Laspeed I'm sorry I updated the answer, the data you should pass on `router.push` must be object.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it as  query params and then get the params from url

```
 router.push(`/${id}?props=${category}`)
```

like this

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the category in query string parameters.
Then in your component you can read it via router.query

Comment: Can you show an exemple or a reference about the same?